# Can't send eth + data into contract with etherjs

Tags: web3js, contract-development, ethers.js, calldata

I want to send eth + data into this contract: **0x5293Bb897db0B64FFd11E0194984E8c5F1f06178** like this transaction: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x64b9b55c3a1ddb68159156dee5dcf8cccaa42b9d9af9ae896df9ecd3a1922ac5

I can do it with myetherwallet:

[image]

But I got failed with etherjs, my code is below:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,waitTimeInMs));

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/my_api_key');
const eth_wei_minimal = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0');
const stream = fs.createReadStream('key_bridge_eth.csv');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: stream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

(async () => {
    var counter = 0;
    var done = 0;
    var errors = 0;

    for await (const line of rl) {
        const [privateKey, data] = line.split(",");
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey.trim(), provider);
        counter++;

        if (Number(await provider.getBalance(wallet.address)) > eth_wei_minimal) {
            try {
                const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(wallet.address);
                console.log(wallet.address);
                const tx = {
                    to: "0x5293Bb897db0B64FFd11E0194984E8c5F1f06178",
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2009900000009".toString()),
                    data: data.trim(),
                    chainID: '11155111',
                    nonce: nonce,
                    gasLimit: 116402,
                    gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('1.7', 'gwei'),
                };
                console.log(data.trim());
                await sleep(1500);
                const recipt = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
                console.log(`tx claim = https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/${recipt.hash}`);

            } catch (err) {
                console.error(`tx ERROR`);
                errors++;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`Processed ${counter} keys, completed ${done} transactions, encountered ${errors} errors.`);
}) ();
```

And here is the data in file: `key_bridge_eth.csv`

> Privatekey, 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

And I get this error: `tx ERROR`

Please give me some advices. Thank you.

Comment: What does the catched error says? It could be a bug in the contract. Can you share the contract code?

Comment: well, I don't have the code. But you can find the contract here: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x5293bb897db0b64ffd11e0194984e8c5f1f06178

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the contract you're sending this transaction to has the appropriate fallback/receive function to receive your transaction? If not then sending ether will always fail.
2. after looking at the transaction you posted, it seems that this user is using the function sendMessage() which takes many arguments. You would need to know that function signature to use it or have the contract's abi. That's not what you're doing, you're sending ether with attached data.